# What to do when a question with a bounty still does not receive attention?

Tags: support, bounty

What do I do when a question does not receive attention even though I added a bounty and tried to increase its quality by editing?

Does this mean the question is low quality and thus is ignored?

I did not ask the question but I could not find any duplicates and no answer when googling and in my opinion it is a very interesting question I'd like to know the answer to.

Should I add additional tags to make it more findable or just let it die? How should I deal with this kind of phenomenon?

Comment: Well, do you still need an answer?  That's why you bountied it in the first place, right?  Then try to improve it.  Don't add additional tags just to widen the audience; that just gets unwelcome attention by people who are now annoyed you did so, and have to edit your question to remove them.  Bounties can't guarantee answers; all they can do is make them more visible and give incentive for others to answer.

Comment: @fbueckert thanks for your response but after already editing the answer, I'm not sure how to improve it any further

Comment: Hard to know what might be the case with this particular interesting question if you don't share a link to it ;) Apparently it's not a bad question so it should have little to fear from meta.

Comment: @Gimby [Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925606/does-adding-babel-plugin-transform-runtime-to-babel-polyfill-reduce-codesize) I didn't want to appear like I'd just asked this question to utilize the meta effect so I did not include it

Comment: I think part of the problem might be that the question is not so much a *bad* question as a *pointless* one. The answer is "Yes/No", and the way to get the answer is to try it and find out. I'm afraid I very much suspect that this Meta question might end up getting the question you put a bounty on downvoted.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I think it isn't about whether you _could_ reduce code size by using the two together, but rather, whether the two components are _supposed_ to be used together in order to achieve these ends

Comment: @TomM: The question doesn't remotely read that way. I can see where you could get there, depending on what sort of assumptions one made about the OP's grasp of English (as what I presume to be a second language), If you're certain that's the OP's question, you should edit it again to clearly make the distinction.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It does not strike me as a question which is factually answerable. Assuming I am right, that would explain an absence of answers.

Answer (score 12):

A question which is bountied but doesn't receive attention has not successfully captured the attention of anyone interested in *that* amount of bounty for it.

In that case, we assume that the question itself is well-phrased and on-topic (since it hasn't been closed with the increased attention to it), and we are left with two options:

- **Increase the bounty amount.**  50 rep isn't a lot and may gain *some* attention.  500 rep gets a *lot* of attention.
- **Let it be.**  It may be the case that Stack Overflow doesn't have any experts to answer your specific question.  This happens sometimes; no sense in beating yourself up about it.  You've done all you could.